# Constructing a warped image given optical flow gradients

Tags: computer-vision

I have gradients for optical flow in the x and y direction, and I am wondering how to transform an image according to those gradients:

The arrow points to the direction of the gradient calculated

[image: The arrow points to the direction of the gradient calculated]

What would be the best way to construct the image for a given time-step along the gradients?

Answer (score 1):

Use a sane warping strategy, preferably based on interpolation. In matlab, use of "interp2" works well. Matlab example:

```
s = 40; %size of data
t = 1;  %time offset

[x,y] = meshgrid(1:s,1:s);

binIm = (x-(s/2)).^2 +((y-(s/2)).^2)*10 <((s/3))^2;

subplot(2,2,1); imagesc(binIm); colormap gray;axis image; 
title('eliptical mask');

%some rotational flow (curl) 
Ur = 10*(y-(s/2))/(s/2); 
Vr = -10*(x-(s/2))/(s/2);

%some zooming flow (divergent) 
Uz = 10*(x-(s/2))/(s/2); 
Vz = 10*(y-(s/2))/(s/2);

binImR = interp2(double(binIm),x-t*Ur,y-t*Vr); 
subplot(2,2,3); imagesc(binImR); axis image;colormap gray; 
hold on; quiver(Ur,Vr); 
title('rotational flow');

binImZ = interp2(double(binIm),x-t*Uz,y-t*Vz); 
subplot(2,2,4); imagesc(binImZ); axis image;colormap gray; 
hold on; quiver(Uz,Vz); 
title('zooming flow');
```

Note that the bigger you make "t", the worse the approximation will become, especially for rotational motion.

Answer (score 0):

-For each pixel, interpolate its gradient using proximity and magnitude of the 4 nearest optical flow values.
-Then apply the time step to the interpolated gradient value to generate a destination location.
-Since the resulting position will not be directly on grid, I would probably calculate a Gaussian centered on the destination based on the origin pixel's intensity.  Then use that Gaussian to add intensity values into the nearby cells in the output image.  Alternately, you could take the intensity (of the original pixel) and do a weighted split of that intensity into the 4 nearest cell centers about the destination location. (i feel like this may blur your image less than a Gaussian)